# Quadrocopter build - Do these parts look fine?

Tags: motor, sensors, quadcopter, multi-rotor

I am completely brand new to quadrocopter building. I am currently about to start building a Quad. I have done a little bit of research and was thinking of buying the following parts:

- KK2.1 Hobbyking Flight Controller
- Turnigy H.A.L Quadcopter Frame
- 4 x NTM Prop Drive    35-30 1100kv / 380w
- Turnigy 9X 9CH
- Turnigy Plush 40A ESC
- Slow Fly Prop Left
- Slow Fly Prop Right
- Quad Power Dist Board
- Turnigy 5Ah 3S25C LiPo

What do you think of these parts/Do you have any complete builds with instructions that you would recommend instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your frame is about (220g + other parts' weight), you need to make sure that your 4 motors give you a combined thrust of atleast 100 g more than, just to get off the ground and maneuver. Anything greater than that is good. [(Thurst Calculator)](http://aeroquad.com/showthread.php?1048-Calculating-motor-thrust). Just looking at the numbers, I think it should work out fine.

You battery amps * burst C / constant C should be greater than the motor amp pull * 4 (using same units, mAh or Ah).

Your ESC amp rating should be higher than the Max current pull of a motor (which it looks to be).

Propellers look OK. Make sure their inner diameter matches motor shaft diameter, else buy adapters.

Rest all looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see that this was such an old question, I'm used to Stack Overflow where the first page of questions spans several minutes instead of several months!

The DJI Naza Flamewheel F450 is a popular kit, I am building one. You can get it at a bunch of different places online, such as [here](http://heli-heli.com/items/quad-copters/dji-innovations/dji-flame-wheel-f450-arf-kit-includes-motors-esc-propellers-dji-fw450-detail.htm). It includes the airframe, motors, ESCs, and props, and because they are from the same kit they are pretty much guaranteed to be compatible.

You will have to source the remaining parts yourself, i.e. the battery, Tx/Rx, and flight controller. Your battery and Tx look fine for the Flamewheel F450 kit, and I can't comment on the Hobbyking FC unit because I have no experience with it (I use the DJI Naza-M Lite).

Also, don't forget the LiPo battery charger!

Hope this helps, good luck with your build!